# Refreshing browser doesn't reflect UI changes because of Manage Versions

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script. I'm working my way through some simple example code, putting together a very simple UI in the Script Editor. After I add each element, I'd like to be able to refresh the browser view to see the latest update. (I'm publishing the script as a Web App.)

So, I add an element to the Ui via script, save my script, and then refresh the browser window. (I've already saved a version and published the script, so I already have a browser window open with that url.) The update is not reflected after the refresh.

It seems the reason is because I didn't save a new version after making the change. If I save a new version, publish the new version, and THEN refresh, I do see the latest version of the UI.

Saving a new version and re-publishing is a very slow way to review my changes as I make them.  Is there some other way to preview Ui changes without having to slog through these steps? I'm not using the GUI Builder, just writing code.

I see the advantage of version management in the bigger picture, but for my situation it makes things quite cumbersome!

I did see a post from June that seemed to ask the same question (How to quickly test saved code in Google Sites?) and there wasn't a solution offered, but I'm not sure if there were other factors in his code that wouldn't apply to me.

Thank you! Carrie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "special" url for that... so you see your changes directly when you save the script.

see screen captures below, it shows up in both screens.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! I didn't realize that link would work quite like that. --Carrie

Comment: thank you! seemed crappy to have to save a version each time esp when dealing with html.